# Subgraph with minimum edge weight and node weight >= Val

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

I came across this problem - In an undirected graph every node and edge has a weight. All the weights are non-negative. Given a value S, Find the connected subgraph with minimum sum of edge weights such that its sum of node weights is at least S.

The most obvious solution is a brute force approach considering all possible subgraphs. But the time complexity is exponential. Is there any better algorithm for this? My intuition is that we can convert node weights to edge weights and then apply spanning tree algorithm. But I couldn't solve it clearly. How to solve this problem?

EDIT : Looks like I was not clear enough about the description of subgraph. The selected subgraph must be a single, connected component. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Are weights constrained at all (e.g. all non-negative)? If all the weights are non-negative, the problem becomes trivial -- perhaps you want to constrain subgraphs to be only those subgraphs induced by a set of edges?

Comment: All the weights are non-negative and all the edges can be considered. How do we solve the problem?

Comment: With those constraints the solution is trivial: choose all the nodes and none of the edges. Edge weight 0, node weight definitely above S unless it's impossible.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. All the chosen nodes must be connected by edges.

Comment: Right, so my suggestion (only subgraphs that are induced by a set of edges) appears on-target; or does "all the chosen nodes must be connected" mean something stronger like "only strongly connected subgraphs"?

Comment: Seems like I was not clear about many things. It's an undirected graph. Yes, we need to consider subgraphs that are induced by a set of edges.

Comment: It's still unclear whether the solution is required to be *connected* (i.e., there is a path from every vertex to every other vertex), or just that every vertex is incident on *some* edge (this would allow separate connected components).

Comment: Check the edit. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say "strongly connected component" instead of "strongly connected subgraph"? A strongly connected component is maximal, and there are efficient algorithms for finding these.

Comment: If you could solve this problem efficiently, could you also solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem efficiently?

Comment: As Daniel Wagner mentioned, "strongly connected" has a specific meaning -- and, in fact, it's a term that can only apply to *directed* graphs.  I'm also 99% sure you just mean "connected" -- and in that case, templatetypedef's reduction is correct, meaning this is NP-hard.

Comment: I didn't knew that strongly connected is used only for directed graphs. I meant connected only. Are there any dynamic programming methods to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem is NP-hard via a reduction from the Steiner tree problem. Given a graph G and a set of nodes S that need to be spanned, set the weight of all of the nodes in S to one and all the other nodes to 0. A subgraph with node weight at least |S| with minimum total edge cost must be a tree (if there are any cycles, deleting an edge from the cycle only decreases the cost) and must connect all of the nodes that need to be spanned. It's therefore a Steiner tree. Overall, this reduction can be computed in polynomial time, so your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: From the update, it seems solutions need not be connected -- so a solution to this problem might be a forest and not a spanning tree, hence not a solution to the Steiner problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner The question still asks about a connected subgraph - perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Yep, you're right -- there's been further clarifications since I wrote my comment. Apologies!

Comment: @templatetypedef Are there any dynamic programming ways of solving this problem?

Comment: @Sashank Not that I know of, though there are good approximation algorithms for Steiner tree in case that helps.